# Insert block in between two blocks on mobile with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to achieve the following layout on desktop:

```
[1][2]
[3][2]
```

I need column 2 to be the height of 1 and 3 on desktop.

Then on mobile I want it to look like:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

I tried 2 options:

Option 1:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <span>1</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                <span>3</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is that block 2 is the height of block 1 only.

Option 2:

I thought about using column ordering to insert block 2 between block 1 and block 3:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div>
                    <span>1</span>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <span>3</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I don't think it's possible this way.

Is there another method I didn't think about? or is it possible using one of the methods above?

Thanks.

Comment: try `flex-layout` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will need a solution in the future, I ended up using flex-direction: column and put height on the container:

**HTML:**

```
        <div id="flex-container" class="row flex-lg-column">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-1">
                <span>1</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-3">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-2">
                <span>3</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {

    #flex-container { 
        max-height: 40rem; 
    }
    #flex-container .order-1, 
    #flex-container .order-2, 
    #flex-container .order-3 { order: initial; }
}
```

And becuase Bootstrap 4 `.row` has flex-wrap: wrap, block 3 will wrap to the right side of the two blocks on lg screens.

Answer (score 0):

**try something like this**

```css
#flex_box1 div
{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  border: 2px solid #555;
  margin-bottom:15px;  
}
#flex_box1 div:last-child{ margin:0; }
#flex_box2 div
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #555; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 d-flex flex-column" id="flex_box1">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 " id="flex_box2">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you. I'm missing the mobile part, how do I insert the grey box between the white boxes on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use library called Masonry. It is quick and easy to implement. Link: https://masonry.desandro.com/

With this you can get desired result for both desktop and mobile version as you mentioned.

Demo:
https://codepen.io/Bibeva/pen/qBExWjj

**HTML:**

```
<!-- bootstrap 4 css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row grid">
  <div class="col-md-6 grid-item">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 grid-item grid-item-box">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 grid-item">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jquery cdn -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- masonry js cdn-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<!-- custom js -->
<script>
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grid-item { 
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}

.grid-item-box { 
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can't use any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container1{
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
 }
.container1 div {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.div1 {
    background: #f60;
}
.div2 {
    background: #f55;
    height: 100vh!important;
}
.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    background: #0ae4dd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>

<pre>
**For Mobile View** 
@media(max-width: 992px){
  .container1{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .container1 div {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .div2 {
    height: auto!important;
  } 
  .div3{
    position:inherit;
  }
}
</pre>
```